# jQuery keypress() event listener

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to execute a function every time a field changes. Just to get started, I am using a simple `textarea` and a div:

```
<div id="text"></div>
<textarea id="stuff"></textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#stuff").keypress(function () {
        $("#text").text($("#stuff").val());
    });
</script>
```

This works, but it is always one character behind. If I type "Hello" on the textarea, the div will just say "Hell".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try .keyUp() that may fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The keypress event fires before the textarea updates it's value based on the keypress that occurred, otherwise the handler wouldn't be able to cancel the event.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/zDMbJ/ which arbitrarily cancels an event if the key pressed was 'A'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#stuff").keyup(function () {
        $("#text").html($(this).val());
    });
</script>
```

http://jsbin.com/ibido3/edit